# Ejecutar con hilos Java

Tags: java, hilos

Estoy buscando una forma para poder ejecutar en paralelo las siguientes dos lineas de código con hilos. He visto algunas opciones, pero todas pasan por crear una clase `Thread`, pero no puedo crear la clase en este caso. No sé muy bien como puedo crear los dos hilos y que se ejecuten en paralelo:

```
list.forEach(reviewsList -> {
    reviewWriter.persistReviews(reviewsList, activeTable);
});
saveInCoherence();

private void saveInCoherence() {
    reviewsMap.forEach((keyMap, reviewList) -> {
        ...
    }
}
```

A modo funcional, lo que hará esto es una parte ir a `Oracle` y hará inserts y la otra parte irá a una caché y cacheará lo mismo. El tema es que el proceso tarda demasiado y por eso me gustaría meter hilos para que ambos procesos vayan en paralelo.

Comment: Implementa Runnable y su metodo run -> http://www.carballude.es/blog/2010/03/01/478/

Comment: No puedo implementar una clase nueva que herede de Thread o Runnable... Tendria que ser algo, de hilos que engloben cada una de esas lineas.

Comment: Pues me temo que imposible entonces.

Comment: ¿Por qué no puedes usar `Thread`?

Comment: Si puedo usar Thread, lo que no puedo hacer es crear una clase que herede de Thread, porque tendría que mover parte del código a la clase y funcionalmente afectaría bastante de lo que hay que cambiar en la implementación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dices que no puedes crear nuevas clases, claramente se hace mas complicado, pero no imposible, cuando tengo que ejecutar algo en `Threads`, creo un `Runnable`

```
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                functionToCall();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("Error to run task", e);
            }
        }
    };
    executor.execute(runnable);
```

Espero te sirva para lo que necesitas.